# .Net 3.5 sp1 unable to start debugging on web server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

When trying to debug my web application, I'm getting an "unable to start debugging on the web server" error then with html displayed right after in the same pop up. All the inline code in the html shows an exception e.g object reference not set, unhandeled exception was generate, etc.

I tried all the suggestions on google to no avail: Windows Authentication in IIS is on, aspnet_regiis -i gives me the "Failed to initialize properly 0xc0000005" error.

This problem only occurs under .Net 3.5 SP1, 3.5 works fine and I made sure it's SP1 by uninstalling and reinstalling it twice. And I also made sure nothing has changed except for the .Net SP1.

Running Win XP,
VS 2008, IIS on same box

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a special case. Posting here just in case others have the same set-up.
The problem is caused by Symantec Endpoint Protection MR5. Rolling back to MR4 did the trick.
Additional info: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/aspnetwpexe-could-not-be-started-error-code-failure-c0000005-when-sep1105-installed

Thanks to all those that have replied.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to solve the problem with aspnet_regiis. Which error is this giving you?

Comment: Hi, it gives me "The application failed to initialize properly 0xc0000005" error. I looked it up on google and was unable to fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried all the google options, but the simplest solution is quite often the right one.

In config, did you check to make sure that the system.web debug attribute is set to true?  That's bitten me a handful of times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes the compilation debug = "true" is there. If I start without debugging, the page will display a server error.